# What exactly is this question asking us to do?

Tags: circuit-analysis, current, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

Based on the model and circuit shown in Fig. 2, draw a circuit model of the path of current through the human body for a person touching a voltage source with both hands who has both feet at the same potential as the negative terminal of the voltage source.

[image]

Is this how the diagram will turn out?

[image]

Is this how the two feet will be connected to V-?

[image]

Alright. Done. But the head resistor is still not connected anywhere.

Comment: Your first attempt at a solution can't be right. Your two \$ R_L \$ resistors are in series which would mean that the left foot is on the floor (battery -) and the right leg has been inserted into the left hip joint so that the right foot is connected to the top of the left thigh and the right thigh is connected to the torso. What is 'Rw'? It doesn't appear on the original diagram. Hint: if both feed are on the ground both \$  R_L \$ resistors must have one terminal connected to what?

Comment: @Transistor That is not "Rw", it's "Rn". That is the resistor in the human's neck.

Comment: The question says that both feet should be at the negative terminal. If I connect the two R(L) resistors in parallel, only the left foot will be at the negative terminal

Comment: Copy the resistor-man drawing and connect up both feet to V- and both hands to V+ as explained in the question. Then redraw it with a rectangular schematic layout. Post a photo of your sketches. Full marks for proper exposure and cropping of your photo - a task that seems to be beyond many contributors.

Comment: I've uploaded another diagram. See if that's getting me somewhere

Comment: Good so far. I would have drawn the floor as a horizontal line. Now connect up the hands to V+. (You can draw a big loop over the head.

Comment: Is the head supposed to be connected to the positive or the negative terminal?

Comment: "*But the head resistor is still not connected anywhere.*" Correct, but you knew that, didn't you? Since the question doesn't mention the head we must assume that it is not touching either wire so it is open-circuit and no current will flow through the head.

Comment: So that's it? This is the final diagram?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from the guidance in the comments:

> So that's it? This is the final diagram?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr1jaC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The solution in conventional format while showing clearly the resistor-man.*

I've added an earth symbol since the man is on the floor. You can leave it out.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. You've been a great help.

Comment: OK. Don't forget to accept the answer to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Oh. How do I do that? Actually I just made an account today so I'm still figuring things out.

Comment: You should see a checkbox under the voting buttons. (There may be a time delay before it appears as you are a new user.) On StackExchange you upvote useful answers and accept the best post that answers your question.

Comment: Alrighty. Done ✅

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed draw how the resistors of your body are aligned in regard to the voltage supply.

Look at the two \$R_A\$ from the arms: How are they connected? Then how is \$R_T\$ connected to them? And in the end, how are both \$R_L\$ connected to them?

Draw a curcuit diagram to show parallel and series connections ;)

Comment: So, in this case the two R(A) are in series and two R(L) are also in series but they are parallel to the R(N) and R(T)?

Comment: There's a schematic button on the editor toolbar. You can add a schematic into your question and we'll help you along. Double-click a component to edit its properties. 'R' to rotate.

Comment: it may help to recognize that the picture of the modeled human body and voltage source does not reflect the written question that follows it. Look what it says about _both_ hands and _both_ feet. Second recognize that resistors disconnected at one end are effectively not part of the circuit.